# BGE: How to make a Key inactive after pressing another Key?

Tags: game-engine, objects, logic-bricks

When pressing <kbd>W</kbd> a cube is doing a forward movement.
When I press <kbd>S</kbd> I want to make the <kbd>W</kbd> movement inactive, how do I do that?

And after by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> again I want the cube to do a back movement, so to do a different type of movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use states: In the first state, you have a <kbd>W</kbd> keyboard sensor, linked to a motion actuator that moves the object forward, and you have an <kbd>S</kbd> keyboard sensor linked to a "Set State" actuator, which will set the second state.

On the second state, you have a <kbd>W</kbd> keyboard sensor, linked to a motion actuator that moves the object backward.

That should produce the desired behavior you described.

Here's a demo, if required: [logic_brick_key_remap.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6rc1r3ynvw5u74j/logic_brick_key_remap.blend?dl=1)

Comment: A complementary `example.blend` is always welcome for newer users (not required however). On a side note, I've been meaning to tell you I loved your tutorials from a few years ago, got me more involved more with the bge :).

Comment: Thank you very much Goran! Highly appreciated! I also like you tutorials.